# Std::vector and Constructor

Tags: c++, project

I have some code like this:

```
class A{

public: 
A();

private:
vector<vector<int> > mat;
int a;

}
```

How the default constructor should look like?Like this?

```
A::A(): mat(10(10)),a(0){};
```

But there's one more problem for me.. I don't know the number of "rows".
(`vector<vector<int> >` should have n elements, and `vector<int>` should have 4 elements) 
And also I have a problem of accessing the elements of `vector<vector<int> >`. So can you tell me how to do? Thanks.:)

Answer (score 5):

Use the constructor under (2) on [this reference page:](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)

```
A::A() : mat(10, std::vector<int>(10)), a(0) { }
```

You can pass variables also, of course. For example:

```
A::A(size_t n_rows, size_t n_cols) : mat(n_rows, std::vector<int>(n_cols)), a(0) {}
```

To access elements, you use two succesive calls to `operator[]`:

```
std::cout << mat[1][1];  // will print 0, as vector's elements are default initialized
```

First call returns a reference to `vector<int>`, the second one a reference to `int`.

Comment: Thanks...:) And do I need to initialize mat? Or can I leave it? What's better?

Comment: The elements are initialized to 0 in the constructor. If that makes sense in your program, then that's obviously it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a constructor that takes the number of rows:

```
A(unsigned int rows): mat(rows, std::vector<int>(4)), a(0) {};
```

For accessing the elements, you can add some access operators or methods. For example

```
class A{

public: 
 public:
 A(unsigned int rows): mat(rows, std::vector<int>(4)), a(0) {};
 const int& operator()(unsigned int row, unsigned int col) const {
   return mat[row][col];
 }
 private:
vector<vector<int> > mat;
int a;

};
```

Then

```
A a;
int i = a(3,4);
```

You may want to add some range checking to the access operator.